# Simple PHP Level-up progress calculations

Tags: php, wordpress, variables, math, levels

I am creating a Level up System for a wordpress blog. I believe that this issue is more towards Php and maths rather than wordpress which is why im asking the question here.

I want users to gain 'levels' when the ratings (or you can call it xp) custom field gets to a multiple of 25 ( *Although I would prefer to have the xp requirement increase exponentially, please look at request #2 below*).

I have this in my **functions.php** file.

```
function movie_level() {
   if ( is_single() ) {
      global $post;
      $movie_level = get_post_meta( $post->ID, "movie_level", true);
      if ( !isset( $movie_level ) OR empty( $movie_level ) OR !is_numeric( $movie_level ) ) {
     $movie_level = 1;
     add_post_meta( $post->ID, "movie_level", $movie_level );
      }
  $vmeta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ratings_score', true );
  $movie_percentage_check = $vmeta / ( 25*$movie_level ) * 100;
  if ( $movie_percentage_check == 100 ) {
         $new_level = $movie_level + 1;
         update_post_meta( $post->ID, "movie_level", $new_level );
         $update_rating = $vmeta + 1;
         update_post_meta( $post->ID, "ratings_score", $update_rating );
      } return $movie_level;
    }
 }
```

What it does is add +1 to movie_movie level when ratings reach 25.

In my **single.php** file i have the following:

```
 $meta = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'ratings_score', true );
 $level= movie_level();
 $perc = $meta / ( 25 * $level ) * 100;

 echo '<div class="progress large-6 small-12 columns "><span class="meter" style="width:'.$perc.'%"><span></span></span></div>';

 echo movie_level();
```

This displays the progress to the next level using a progress bar css component.

## Requests

1. How can I make $perc start at 0% again when  an new level is reached? With my current equation the progress bar will always show progress starting from level 1 - level 3(for example), rather than level 2 - level 3.
2. How can I update my code so that the ratings requirement increases exponentially for each level and still achieve what I wanted in request #1

Comment: Have you tried anything to accomplish the additional requests? Show that code too if you have it.

Comment: If you want to calculate percentages on values with an “offset”, then of course you have to subtract that offset from both values before. Lets say level 7 starts at 400 points, level 8 at 500, and the user currently has 471 points. 500 - 400 is 100, 471 - 400 is 71 – makes 71% “into” level seven. Works the same if the values are not so “nicely” chosen as in this example of course.

Comment: Do you mean `( 5 * $level )` in the second code block, should that be `25`? Otherwise I'm confused as to where the `5` comes from.

Comment: @SpaceDog sorry i must have accidentally deleted the 2 in front of five.

Comment: @FDL I did try to, but with Mircosoft excel and a pen and paper to work out the correct forumula unfortunatley. Scrapped them both because of no luck. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're jumping through some hoops you don't need to, but a couple of notes first.

In the `movie_level` function you're checking if the level needs increased, it only makes sense to do that check when the associated variables have changed -- i.e. make the change when you update `movie_level` or `ratings_score`. Also you return `movie_level`, but that doesn't reflect the `+ 1` if you've added it, so you always return the old score (as you use `new_level` to store the new score). That might be what you intend, but I suspect it's not.

The key question you're trying to answer is -- how far to the next level? For blocks of 25 the next level is `(movie_level * 25)` and the amount to the next level is `(movie_level * 25) - rating_score`. As a percentage it's `((movie_level * 25) - rating_score) / 25` (maybe `* 100` if you want).

That works with fixed blocks, for exponential blocks you could explicitly store next target as a variable. But you can apply the same logic as above, assume that the function `level_target(x)` returns the target score for level `x`. Then you can work out how far to go with `level_target(movie_level) - rating_score`, but you need to know the size of that level which is `level_target(movie_level) - level_target(movie_level - 1)`.

So to get the percentage do: `(level_target(movie_level) - rating_score)/(level_target(movie_level) - level_target(movie_level - 1))`

You can implement `level_target` as function, or work out what you want and incorporate it directly which would allow you to simplify the equation.

Exponential level increases are going to get very big rapidly, so you might want a maximum on there. But if you want

```
 0, 25, 50, 100, 200, 400 ...
```

you can note that it's equivalent to

```
 25 * 0, 25 * 1, 25 * 2, 25 * 4, 25 * 8, 25 * 16 ...
```

and then note that the sequence 0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 16 ... are just increasing powers of two. So `level_target(x) = 25 * pow(2,x)`.

The reason it might be more useful to store the next target level as a separate variable is that you can just double the old target level and avoid ever having to do the powers of 2 thing (and you can work out the difference it levels because it'll always be exactly half the level target).

**EDIT**

To clarify my field change comment. You only need to recalculate movie_level after rating_score changes (or vice versa), so typically you would only recalculate the variables when one changes.

I don't know your application, but assume that there's only one page where the values of movie_level and/or rating_score can change (an edit score page, say) but there are dozens of other pages that all show the progress bar. If you check `($movie_percentage_check == 100)` only on the page where the values change then you don't need to check anywhere else (because the values cannot change anywhere else so you can know it's not true).

It's not necessarily bad to check that on all the view pages, particularly for a simple site. And there are cases where you'd need to (if some other part of the system can update the values somehow). In a more complex system you want to avoid doing work you don't need to so only 'edit' pages should change the values, 'view' pages should just read/use the values.

I've maybe not explained that well, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thanks, the math plays out perfectly!!. I understand everything apart from detecting when a field has change. Do you have an example i can refer to?.
Also i understand what you're saying about the rapid increase if i use exponential growth, even cubic growth increases a lot as well. DO you think i should just stick to fixed blocks?.

Comment: The choice of increase really depends on your users and what you're doing. You could also add a percentage each time, 25 + 20% increase gives 0, 25, 55, 91, but you'll end up with non-integers as the next number is 134.2.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand. The function should check when the ratings_score changes rather than constantly checking for movie_level to be 100 right?. The ratings_score changes when someone presses a button on the post page to give a *thumbs up*(done through ajax with help of a plugin). I'll do some digging to find how to detect change of values using php. Do you want an update on my findings?

Also, 25+20% gives a reasonable increase. Will using intval to keep them as integers work?.

Comment: That sounds good, the target of the ajax script is probably PHP that updates the value -- so add the logic to update movie_level in there. You could easily just round the values to integers if you want, I would think that would work (depends if your users will notice, probably not). You can always come back to post an answer that explains what you finally did to help other people who search for similar questions.